# Is there a way to compress a check that returns a nullable boolean this into 1-2 lines?

Tags: c#, simplify

I'm making a simple C# console app and the user has to input either a 1 or a 2 to select their option, and obviously since the user can enter absolutely anything, I need to make a check that returns their input and if it isn't a 1 or a 2, it'll return null.

This is what I made

```
bool? getResponse = null;
if (read == "1")
{
    getResponse = true;
}
else if (read == "2")
{
    getResponse = false;
}
else
{
    getResponse = null;
}
```

Knowing C#, there's definitely a way to simplify this but I cant seem to find a way to online. Any pointers?

Comment: You can use a switch expression. If you’re not comfortable with the syntax, you can use a switch statement instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [conditional operator `?:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

But this could be **complex to maintain** and **difficult to read** if the **logic is getting complex** (adding logic for `read == "3"` and etc.).

```cs
getResponse = read == "1" 
    ? true 
    : read == "2" 
        ? false 
        : null;
```

Another approach you can apply is [switch expression for C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression).

```cs
getResponse = read switch
{
    "1" => true,
    "2" => false,
    _ => null,
};
```

The third approach is you work around with `Dictionary`.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

Dictionary<string, bool> resultDict = new Dictionary<string, bool>
{
    { "1", true },
    { "2", false }
};
        
getResponse = resultDict.TryGetValue(read, out bool _result) 
    ? _result 
    : null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) in a such situations like this

```
string read = Console.ReadLine();

bool? response = read == "1" ? true
: read == "2" ? false : null;
```

but it's best when there is only 2 possible ways, as u can see it's getting out of hand easily. In this situation my code above is ok, but if you have like 10 possibilities maybe something like this is a good approach

```
// lets say there is ways 
// 1 = true, 2 = false, 3 = null
// and any other input means exception

string read = Console.ReadLine()!;

Dictionary<string, bool?> keyValues = new();
keyValues.Add("1", true);
keyValues.Add("2", false);
keyValues.Add("3", null);

bool? response = keyValues.ContainsKey(read) ? keyValues[read] 
    : throw new Exception();
```

the exception here is just for example,
my point is that when you have multiple possibilities
doing such thing with dictionary seems much cleaner than if/else, switch/case or multiconditional ternery operator

Answer (score 1):

I consider this pretty unreadable, but it avoids the nested ternary.

`getResponse = int.TryParse(read, out var i) && i > 0 && i < 3 ? (bool)(2-i) : null;`

Parse the `string` into an `int`, make sure it is the valid range, and then do some math so you can cast it to a `bool`. When casting an integer type to a `bool`, 0 means `false`, and non-zero means `true`.